# Working with epoch time in PowerShell using UniversalTime

Tags: powershell, datetime, epoch

This is probably a super simple question, but I'm a bit frustrated now because I can't find exactly what I'm looking for on the internet.

I am trying to convert a PowerShell DateTime to Epoch time using universal time.

I can do either, but can't seem to find a working command to do both.

Here is what I know I can do:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
Wednesday, November 15, 2017 5:07:35 PM
```

And:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Date -UFormat %s
1510747694.20287
```

But, how do I combine them so that I get seconds since epoch in UTC? Everything I try just gives me errors about unexpected token "UFormat" or String does not have method "ToUniversalTime."

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you look at `Get-Help Get-Date` the first parameter is a `-Date` option.  We can use that to our advantage by wrapping our `Get-Date` in another `Get-Date` like so:

```
$epochseconds = Get-Date (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime() -UFormat %s
return $epochseconds
```